# Problems with maze generation using a non-recursive backtracking algorithm

Tags: java, android, maze

I'm working on a game for Android where the explorable areas will be randomly generated. Right now I'm just trying to get the maze generated (with some ASCII art output so I can see it), and I've been at it for about 4-5 days now but I'm just stumped.

I'm trying to use the "depth-first search" algorithm, and all the examples I could find use recursive backtracking. Since this is for Android and phones are relatively wimpy, the recursion quickly leads to a call stack overflow, which is why I'm trying to write my own algorithm using a stack for backtracking.

I came up with this solution, using a MazeGenerator class and a MazeCell class.

MazeGenerator:

```
package com.zarokima.mistwalkers.explore;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.path.Direction;
import android.graphics.Point;

public class MazeGenerator
{
private int x, y; // the dimensions of the maze
private MazeCell[][] maze;
private Random rand = new Random();
private Stack<MazeCell> stack;

public MazeGenerator(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    generateMaze();
}

public void setSeed(long seed)
{
    rand.setSeed(seed);
}

public void setSize(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public String outputMazeText()
{
    String output = new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        // draw the north edge
        for (int k = 0; k < x; k++)
        {
            output += maze[k][i].hasNeighbor(Direction.UP) ? "+   " : "+---";
        }
        output += "+\n";
        // draw the west edge
        for (int k = 0; k < x; k++)
        {
            output += maze[k][i].hasNeighbor(Direction.LEFT) ? "    " : "|   ";
        }
        output += "|\n";
    }
    // draw the bottom line
    for (int k = 0; k < x; k++)
    {
        output += "+---";
    }
    output += "+\n";

    return output;
}

public void generateMaze()
{
    maze = new MazeCell[x][y];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < y; k++)
        {
            maze[i][k] = new MazeCell(i, k);
        }
    }

    MazeCell.setBounds(x, y);

    stack = new Stack<MazeCell>();
    stack.push(maze[0][0]);
    maze[0][0].setInMaze(true);

    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        MazeCell currentCell = stack.peek();

        Direction[] possibleDirections = currentCell.getUncheckedDirections();

        if (possibleDirections.length == 0)
        {
            stack.pop();
            continue;
        }

        int dint = rand.nextInt(possibleDirections.length);
        Direction direction = possibleDirections[dint];

        MazeCell nextCell = null;
        Point position = currentCell.getPosition();

        switch (direction)
        {
            case UP:
                nextCell = maze[position.x][position.y - 1];
                break;
            case DOWN:
                nextCell = maze[position.x][position.y + 1];
                break;
            case LEFT:
                nextCell = maze[position.x - 1][position.y];
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                nextCell = maze[position.x + 1][position.y];
                break;
        }

        currentCell.setNeighbor(nextCell, direction);

        stack.push(nextCell);
    }
}
}
```

MazeCell:

```
package com.zarokima.mistwalkers.explore;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.anddev.andengine.util.path.Direction;
import android.graphics.Point;

public class MazeCell
{   
private MazeCell[] neighbors;
private boolean[] checked;
private boolean inMaze = false;
private Point position;
private static boolean setNeighbor = true; //whether the next call of SetNeighbor() should also call for the new neighbor
private static int xMax = 10, yMax = 10; //exclusive boundary for position
private int mapIndex; //will be used when maze generation is working properly

public MazeCell(int x, int y)
{
    position = new Point(x,y);
    neighbors = new MazeCell[4];
    checked = new boolean[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++)
    {
        neighbors[i] = null;
    }
}

public Point getPosition()
{
    return position;
}

public void setInMaze(boolean b)
{
    inMaze = b;
}

public static void setBounds(int x, int y)
{
    xMax = x;
    yMax = y;
}

public void setNeighbor(MazeCell c, Direction d)
{
    checked[d.ordinal()] = true;
    switch(d)
    {
        case UP:
            if(!c.hasNeighbor(Direction.DOWN) && !c.isInMaze());
            {
                if(setNeighbor)
                {
                    setNeighbor = false;
                    c.setNeighbor(this, Direction.DOWN);
                }
                neighbors[d.ordinal()] = c;
            }
            break;
        case DOWN:
            if(!c.hasNeighbor(Direction.UP) && !c.isInMaze())
            {
                if(setNeighbor)
                {
                    setNeighbor = false;
                    c.setNeighbor(this, Direction.UP);
                }
                neighbors[d.ordinal()] = c;
            }
            break;
        case LEFT:
            if(!c.hasNeighbor(Direction.RIGHT) && !c.isInMaze())
            {
                if(setNeighbor)
                {
                    setNeighbor = false;
                    c.setNeighbor(this, Direction.RIGHT);
                }
                neighbors[d.ordinal()] = c;
            }
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            if(!c.hasNeighbor(Direction.LEFT) && !c.isInMaze())
            {
                if(setNeighbor)
                {
                    setNeighbor = false;
                    c.setNeighbor(this, Direction.LEFT);
                }
                neighbors[d.ordinal()] = c;
            }
            break;

    }
    setNeighbor = true;
    inMaze = true;
}

public void setDirectionChecked(Direction d, boolean b)
{
    checked[d.ordinal()] = b;
}

public boolean hasNeighbor(Direction d)
{
    return (neighbors[d.ordinal()] != null);
}

public MazeCell getNeighbor(Direction d)
{
    return neighbors[d.ordinal()];
}

public boolean isInMaze()
{
    return inMaze;
}

public Direction[] getUncheckedDirections()
{
    ArrayList<Direction> al = new ArrayList<Direction>();

    for(Direction d : Direction.values())
    {
        //boundary cases
        switch(d)
        {
            case UP:
                if(position.y == 0)
                    continue;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                if(position.y == yMax-1)
                    continue;
                break;
            case LEFT:
                if(position.x == 0)
                    continue;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                if(position.x == xMax-1)
                    continue;
                break;
        }
        if(checked[d.ordinal()] == false)
            al.add(d);
    }

    Direction[] d = new Direction[al.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
        d[i] = al.get(i);

    return d;
}
}
```

This produces results that look like [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2437386/Screenshot_2012-02-08-23-33-29.jpg)

Notice how every cell always connects to its up and down neighbors. I have not been able to figure out what is wrong here.

Although the checks in MazeCell's setNeighbor function seem like they should be enough, I added a few more just to see what would happen. Here is the second generateMaze() method:

```
public void generateMaze()
{
    maze = new MazeCell[x][y];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < y; k++)
        {
            maze[i][k] = new MazeCell(i, k);
        }
    }

    MazeCell.setBounds(x, y);

    stack = new Stack<MazeCell>();
    stack.push(maze[0][0]);
    maze[0][0].setInMaze(true);

    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        MazeCell currentCell = stack.peek();

        Direction[] possibleDirections = currentCell.getUncheckedDirections();

        if (possibleDirections.length == 0)
        {
            stack.pop();
            continue;
        }

        int dint = rand.nextInt(possibleDirections.length);
        Direction direction = possibleDirections[dint];
        currentCell.setDirectionChecked(direction, true);

        MazeCell nextCell = null;
        Point position = currentCell.getPosition();

        switch (direction)
        {
            case UP:
                nextCell = maze[position.x][position.y - 1];
                break;
            case DOWN:
                nextCell = maze[position.x][position.y + 1];
                break;
            case LEFT:
                nextCell = maze[position.x - 1][position.y];
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                nextCell = maze[position.x + 1][position.y];
                break;
        }

        if (!nextCell.isInMaze())
        {
            currentCell.setNeighbor(nextCell, direction);

            stack.push(nextCell);
        }
    }
```

And it produces results like [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2437386/Screenshot_2012-02-09-22-23-44.jpg)

Notice how segments are all broken up.

I've played around with it a *lot* more than just what is mentioned here, but nothing that shows any real improvement -- most end up just looking like the second picture. Any help?

Comment: Backtracking is recursive by definition, even if you are using your own stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating a function called `Direction oppositeOf(Direction d)` (with obvious logic). This function allows you to remove the switch statement entirely in `setNeighbor` if added.
Here I've rewritten `setNeighbor` to have the exact same logic as above, just using this function:

```
    public void setNeighbor(MazeCell c, Direction d)
    {
        checked[d.ordinal()] = true;
        if (!c.isInMaze() && !c.hasNeighbor(oppositeOf(d)))
        {
            if (setNeighbor)
            {
                setNeighbor = false;
                c.setNeighbor(this, oppositeOf(d));
            }
            neighbors[d.ordinal()] = c;
        {
        setNeighbor = true;
        inMaze = true;
    }
```

...which actually exposes that `setNeighbor` boolean *always* equates to true (regardless of if it's set false, it's always then set true), which I'm willing to bet you don't want it to do.

This might not be your biggest problem, there might be other logic errors.

Comment: The setNeighbor boolean always equates to true after the function call, which is fine, since whenever it's called from the MazeGenerator, both currentCell and nextCell need to be set as neighbors of each other, so by setting it to false before calling it for nextCell within currentCell, nextCell will not in turn call it again for currentCell, but it will be reset to true afterward for the next iteration (since it's a static variable). It's a messy way of handling that, but it just kind of arose that way. I do like the idea of Direction.oppositeOf, though. Thanks.

Comment: My point is, the way that it is written the `setNeighbor` boolean never does anything with the code you have here. It's never checked in an if statement when it can be false.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the recursive algorithms you found are just fine. You just need to transform them to an iterative one by using a stack or a queue instead of a recursive call (you simulate your call-stack). You can find a nice example for [breadth first](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/breadth-first/) iteration [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/breadth-first/). Hope this helps and you can adapt this to your problem.